# What does USE INDEX() without an index_list do?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I had a query that was taking a very long time to process (>60 secs):

```
                SELECT
                    r.name,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.name
                        SEPARATOR ',') AS other_s,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT sr.pk) AS total_u,
                    r.distance,
                    r.pk as 'index'
                FROM
                    st.r r
                        LEFT JOIN
                    st.rs rs ON (r.pk = rs.rfk)
                        INNER JOIN
                    st.srr srr ON (srr.rfk = r.pk)
                        LEFT JOIN
                    st.s s ON (rs.sfk = s.pk) INNER JOIN
                    st.sr sr ON (srr.srfk = sr.pk)
                WHERE r.delete_date IS NULL AND
                      r.pk IN (SELECT
                            route_fk
                        FROM
                            st.srr
                        WHERE
                            srfk = 3)
                GROUP BY r.name , r.distance
```

I was advised to add in use index() to this line:

```
                FROM
                    st.r r use index()
```

And, almost magically, the query now takes around 15 secs to process.

According to: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html#:~:text=The%20USE%20INDEX%20(%20index_list%20)%20hint,some%20particular%20index%20or%20indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html#:%7E:text=The%20USE%20INDEX%20(%20index_list%20)%20hint,some%20particular%20index%20or%20indexes)

> It is syntactically valid to omit index_list for USE INDEX, which means “use no indexes.” Omitting index_list for FORCE INDEX or IGNORE INDEX is a syntax error.

My question is, how does omitting index_list and therefore using no indexes, actually speed up this query?

Comment: Try using `EXPLAIN` to see how the query is optimized with and without the `USE INDEX()`.

Comment: thank you i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using an index means looking through the index (which might be efficient), then jumping over to the data.  Note that the `INDEX` and the data are stored in separate BTrees.
- Using no indexes avoids the back-and-forth.
- *Sometimes* the optimizer makes the wrong decision.

Your query probably suffers from "explode-implode":

1. The `JOINs` create a big temporary table with the combinations of info from the tables.
2. The `GROUP BY` shrinks the info back down.

Meanwhile, you had to do `DISTINCT` to avoid getting duplicate concatenated values and inflated `COUNTs`.

Try to rewrite the query by getting the `GROUP_CONCAT` and the `COUNT` with as simple a query as possible.  *Then* do the rest of the `JOINs` to get the rest of the info.  The will probably run a lot faster *and* avoid the confusion over what, if any, index to use.

Mixing `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` makes my head spin, so I don't want to try to suggest a rewrite.